# Truncated hypergeometric functions modulo prime power

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, hypergeometric-functions

The question arises when I was trying to understand some congruence equations of  [Zhi-wei Sun](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.4453v20.pdf). [C. Herbert Clemens](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4684-7000-0) shows an amazing connection between the number of points on Legendre's Family $$E_\lambda:y^2=x(x-1)(x-\lambda)$$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ and the truncated hypergeometric series $$F(\lambda)=\sum_{m=0}^{(p-1)/2}\frac{(\frac{1}{2})_m^2}{(1)_m^2}\lambda^m.$$The number $a_p(\lambda)$ defined by $$a_p(\lambda)=p+1-\#E_\lambda(\mathbb{F}_p)$$ is the trace of Frobenius of the Legendre family. Clemens shows that $$a_p(\lambda)\equiv(-1)^{(p-1)/2}F(\lambda)\mod p$$ and attributes the discovery of the connection to Manin.

**Question:** Is there a similar interpretation for $F(\lambda)$ modulo prime powers?

Comment: Not $F(\lambda)$ but similar (longer) sums are related to the trace of Frobenius modulo higher powers of $p$. This is the basic idea of Dwork's approach to the rationality of the zeta function.